# SigV4 requests to a regional API Gateway behind Route53

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, amazon-route53

Currently we have the setup Route53 -> Regional API Gateway (us-west-2, us-east-1). We want clients to sign the request using SigV4, which takes region into account. I am seeing the below error when testing from postman with region us-east-1, works fine for us-west-2.

```
{
    "message": "Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-west-2'. "
}
```

I see since the requests from Route53 are routed by latency-based there can be a chance that the region used for signing would be different from the region the request routed to (like when API in a region is down). Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Are the API, ACM certificate and domain all created in the us-west-2 region?

Comment: I have API, certificate, domain in both regions. I wanted to support a multi-region API with Route53 routing to nearest region by latency where API is available.

Comment: @Ajay did you figure this out? - I'm having the same issue

Comment: Our service is not latency critical, we dropped the idea of using Route53 and shared a list of API regional endpoints to the clients, they round robin through them if an endpoint is not available. If you have to use Route53 then I think the client can use the IP address from `host` lookup and then do a `reverse DNS lookup` to get full hostname, which will have the region name. Then client sign using that region. There are still chances that this approach will also run into same error.